# Load dynamic list of elements AFTER FINISHED loading of several form elements

Tags: asp.net, jquery

**I have...**

- a dynamic populated select box
- several input boxes
- a submit button
- form fields are loaded initially using cookies
- **several dynamic populated divs**

**I want...**

- **start loading** the content of my DIVs **after** all FORM elements have been loaded completely (= filled with data, select boxes are populated)

**Sample code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // Populate <select>
    var options ='';
    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
      options += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i +  '</option>';
    }
    $("select#myid").html(options);

  })

  ...
</script>

<form>
   <select id="myselect></select>
   <input id="mytext" type="text" value="" />    
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />    
</form>

<% foreach( MyElement element in MyListing) { %>
  <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
         DoSomething($(select#myid).val());
       })
    </script>
  </div>
<% } %>
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for the extra information:

```
jQuery(function($) {   // note that this is equivalent to $(document).load()
    // if we are here, then all your page and form elements have loaded.

    // Populate <select> as per your code above

    $('div').each(function(index) {    // perhaps give them a class?
        $(this).load(<<someURL>>);
        // it's not clear from your question how you intend to get the
        // dynamic content, ie: what url to use?
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, but how to handle the first page load? In my real project I'm setting the selected option based on stored cookies on the first page load. So I don't want to react on the changed event, I want to react on a Event sent when the select box is loaded completly. But thanks for the answer +1.

Comment: @hkda150 I've updated the response now. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Edited my answer to make the problem more obvious: Using the change() - Event would work for a single select element. What about having several form elements? 
(I'm trying to find a general solution for problems with dynamic populated forms and the result on the same site)